# Implementing asynchronous API call sequence in RXJava

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

I have an array of objects retrieved from my local DB and needs to be uploaded to server in sequence of API calls.
For each local DB object I have to call two asynchronous API calls(methodA(),methodB()) subsequently. After going through the whole loop I need to call another API call as follows.

```
for(Object object: localDBObjects){
    methodA() -> methodB()
}
methodC()
```

My problem is how can I block the methodC() call until finishing the loop.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
public class Main {

public static CountDownLatch finishLatch = new CountDownLatch(1); 

public static Integer methodA(Integer obj) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000)); //Simulate asynchronous call
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println("methodA for " + obj + " executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return obj;
}

public static Integer methodB(Integer obj) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 1000)); //Simulate asynchronous call
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println("methodB for " + obj + " executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return obj;
}

public static void methodC() {
    System.out.println("methodC executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    finishLatch.countDown(); //Allow main to finish
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<Integer> objectsFromDb = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); //List of objects from the DB

    Observable.from(objectsFromDb) 
            .flatMap(obj -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> methodA(obj)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())) //Asynchronously call method A
            .flatMap(obj -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> methodB(obj)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())) //Asynchronously call method B
            .doOnCompleted(() -> methodC()) //When finished, call methodC
            .subscribe();

    finishLatch.await(); //Wait for everything to finish
}
```

}

Sample output:

```
methodA for 5 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-5
methodA for 2 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
methodA for 1 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
methodB for 1 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
methodB for 2 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-5
methodB for 5 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-6
methodA for 3 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
methodA for 4 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-4
methodB for 3 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
methodB for 4 executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
methodC executed by RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to I haven't got a lot of information about your project and concrete implementation of methods, namely their arguments and return types, I have 2 assumtions.

**Note**: I hope you don't mind if I'll use lambda-expressions.

1). Methods return `Observable<Object>` like `Retrofit`
In this case, they looks like this:

```
public Observable<Object> methodA(Object o){
    return null;
}

public Observable<Object> methodB(Object o){
    return null;
}

public Observable<Object> methodC(Object[] objects){
    return null;
}
```

For this case you may use something like this:

```
Object[] localDBObjects = new Object[10];
Observable.just(localDBObjects)
        .flatMap(objects -> Observable.from(objects)
                                .flatMap(object -> methodA(object))
                                .flatMap(resultFromMethodA -> methodB(resultFromMethodA))
                                .toList())
        .flatMap(listOfResultsFromMethodB -> methodC(listOfResultsFromMethodB.toArray(new Object[listOfResultsFromMethodB.size()])))
        .subscribe(resultFromMethodC -> {
            //do something
        }, t -> t.printStackTrace());
```

2). In other case, ,methods return the `Object` like this:

```
public Object methodA(Object o){
    return null;
}

public Object methodB(Object o){
    return null;
}

public Object methodC(Object[] objects){
    return null;
}
```

In this case you need to change operators `flatMap( )` to `map( )` in some places:

```
    Object[] localDBObjects = new Object[10];
    Observable.just(localDBObjects)
            .flatMap(objects -> Observable.from(objects)
                                    .map(object -> methodA(object))
                                    .map(resultFromMethodA -> methodB(resultFromMethodA))
                                    .toList())
            .map(listOfResultsFromMethodB -> methodC(listOfResultsFromMethodB.toArray(new Object[listOfResultsFromMethodB.size()])))
            .subscribe(resultFromMethodC -> {
                //do something
            }, t -> t.printStackTrace());
```